# How can I use Mediapipe handrecognition (using C++) with video feed from other than webcam

Tags: c++, mediapipe

Mediapipe handrecognition example uses webcam to feed itself. Also outputs to screen. I need to feed input stream and get output stream programmaticaly. I cannot find any c++ examples for it. There are python, javascript and android API's. But c++ examples works only from graph. So i cannot find an example to feed it manually. Is there any easy solution ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.